# OnChanged immediately invoked after observe has been called

Tags: android

After observe() is called with nameObserver passed as parameter, onChanged() is immediately invoked providing the most recent value stored in mCurrentName.

I’m trying to understand what this means, does this mean that the first time we attach our observer to our live data, the on Changed is automatically called, and it isn’t called again until the observer either goes from an inactive state to an active one or data changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documents of LiveData method observe you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData)

> Adds the given observer to the observers list within the lifespan of the given owner. The events are dispatched on the main thread. If LiveData already has data set, it will be delivered to the observer.

It means when you observe livedata already set value it will be dispatch immediately.

In case you observe and lifecycle you pass to it in inactive state it will be dispatch again when your lifecycle come to active state. More detail please check [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

> Always up to date data
>   If a lifecycle becomes inactive, it receives the latest data upon becoming active again. For example, an activity that was in the background receives the latest data right after it returns to the foreground.

Comment: Hai The dispatching of values is the same as calling the onChanged method, with the value as the parameter, so whenever observe is called values are dispatched with the use of the onChanged method yeah?

Comment: Yes, I mean dispatch value same onChanged is called